# Ragged2e preventing proper hyphenation of long chemical names

Tags: spacing, hyphenation, chemistry, ragged2e

In my thesis I use chemical names containing dashes and numbers in section titles. Additionally, each compound is numbered by using the `\cmpd{}` command from `chemnum`-package. To prevent the label from being printed on a new line, `\usepackage{ragged2e} \let\raggedsection\RaggedRight` is used.

This seems to prevent proper hyphenation of the compound's name, which then runs into the margin. I tried to insert hyphenation markers via `\-` which has no effect as well as `\protect\linebreak` and `\newline`, which will produce weird spacing and hyphenation in the table of contents. Also, using `chemmacros`'s `\iupac{}`-command and inserting breaking points manually won't work.

How can I hyphenate the work correctly (after the dash and before 2,3,6,7) while keeping the modification done with `ragged2e`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[abstracton, twoside, listof=totoc]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
 \let\raggedsection\RaggedRight

\begin{document}

 \tableofcontents

 \section{Synthese von 9,10-Dihydro-9,10-etheno\-an\-thra\-cen-2,3,6,7-tetra\-carbon\-säure\-tetra\-methylester \cmpd+{a}}

 \section{Synthese von 9,10-Dihydro-9,10-ethenoanthracen-\protect\linebreak 2,3,6,7-tetracarbonsäuretetramethylester \cmpd+{a}}

 \section{Synthese von 9,10-Dihydro-9,10-ethenoanthracen-\newline2,3,6,7-tetracarbonsäuretetramethylester \cmpd+{a}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: ragged2e sets a rather small rightskip, you can enlarge it a bit to allow latex more freedom when looking for a hyphenation point `\RaggedRightRightskip 0pt plus 4em`  (default is plus 2em).

Comment: How do you insert breakpoints in `\iupac`

Comment: The following code is used trying to indicate breaking points: `\iupac{9,10\-Di|hy|dro\-9,10\-etheno|an|thra|cen\-2,3,6,7\-te|tra|car|bon|säure|te|tra|methyl|ester}`. Ulrike's answer seems to do the trick for me, but as I'm not fully aware of what this option does I'm wondering if there are unwanted side effects to this solution?

Comment: @Mundus are you aware that `|` in `\iupac` also inserts a thin space (and disables ligatures)?

Comment: Actually I was not, which makes this approach even more unsuitable for me.

Comment: @Mundus the thin space can be removed using an option. `|` is meant to insert “logical” breakpoints. The thin space is meant to improve readability of those long names. It doesn't make sense to insert it at every possible breakpoint. Words are still allowed to break at other points.

Comment: I believe that allowing breaks after commas in a IUPAC name would not be too unsensible. `\newcommand\commabreak{\babelhyphen{,}} \NewChemIUPACShorthand,\commabreak` would add that. Then `\section{Synthese von \iupac{9,10-Di|hydro-9,10-etheno|anthracen-2,3,6,7-tetra|carbonsäure|tetra|methyl|ester} (\cmpd+{a})}` would break between `6,` and `7`.